# Vue Carousel on iOS Safari only works with first slide

Tags: css, ios, iphone, vue.js, carousel

Good morning, I've build a custom vue carousel and implemented it into my progressive web app. Works fine on Chrome Android, whereas on iOS Safari - id doesn't. I received feedback that the carousel only allows to slide the first page and on the second - it doesn't react.

The problem is, I don't own Mac or Iphone and for now I can't test it myself. Could someone help me out and test the carousel on aforementioned devices? Here is the fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/LSliwa/97cpgq3z/

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <Carousel>
     <div  v-for="(todo, index) in todos" :key="index">
       <div class="app__element">
          {{ todo.text }}
       </div>
    </div>
  </Carousel>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#app {
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.app__element {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}

/* carousel styles */

.carousel {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
} 

.carousel-navdots {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.carousel-navdot {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 0 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  background-color: #05AA19;
}

.carousel-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  cursor: grab;
}

.carousel-wrapper:active {
  cursor: grabbing;
}

.carousel-wrapper>div,
.carousel-wrapper>p,
.carousel-wrapper>span,
.carousel-wrapper>ul {
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.scrolling {
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.inactive {
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .inactive {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
}
```

JS:

```
Vue.component('Carousel', {
  template: '<div class="carousel"><div class="carousel-navdots" v-if="isActive" v-show="pagination"><div class="carousel-navdot" :class="{ \'active\': n == currentPage + 1 }" v-for="n in numberOfPages" v-show="numberOfPages > 1" :key="n" ref="navdot" @click="scrollWithNavdots(n)"></div></div><div class="carousel-wrapper a-stretch" :class="{ \'inactive\': !isActive }" :style="{ transform: `translateX(${translate}px)` }" ref="wrapper" v-on="isActive && active ? { touchstart: onTouchStart, touchmove: onTouchMove, touchend: onTouchEnd, mousedown: onTouchStart, mousemove: onTouchMove, mouseup: onTouchEnd } : {}"><slot></slot></div></div>',
  props: {
      active: {
        type: Boolean, 
        default: () => true
      },
      activeOnViewport: { 
        type: Array,
        default: () => [[1, true]]
      },
      columns: { 
        type: Array,
        default: () => [[1, 1]]
      }, 
      pagination: {
        type: Boolean, 
        default: () => true
      }, 
      sensitivity: {
        type: Number, 
        default: () => 40
      }, 
      startFromPage: {
        type: Number, 
        default: () => 0
      }, 
      autoplay: {
        type: Boolean, 
        default: () => false
      }, 
      autoplaySpeed: {
        type: Number, 
        default: () => 5
      }, 
      // usuń custom length jeżeli rerendering z :key zadziała
      customLength: {
        type: Number
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        currentPage: this.startFromPage,
        numberOfColumns: 1,
        moveStart: null, 
        move: null, 
        currentTranslate: 0,
        length: this.customLength == null ? this.$slots.default.length : this.customLength,
        viewportColumnsMatched: null, 
        isActive: null, 
        mousedown: false,
        elementWidth: 0, 
        autoplayInterval: null, 
        animateTimeout: null,
        test: {
          touchmove: false, 
          touchstart: false,
        }
      }
    },
    computed: {
      maxScrollLeft() {
        return this.currentPage == 0 ? true : false;
      },
      maxScrollRight() {
        return this.currentPage + 1 == this.numberOfPages ? true : false;
      },
      numberOfPages() {
        return Math.ceil(this.length / this.numberOfColumns);
      },
      sortedColumns() {
        return this.columns.sort((a, b) => {
          return a[0] - b[0];
        });
      }, 
      sortedActive() {
        return this.activeOnViewport.sort((a, b) => {
          return a[0] - b[0];
        })
      },
      translate() {
        return -this.elementWidth * this.currentPage
      }
    },
    watch: {
      currentPage() {
        this.animateCarousel();
        this.$emit('change-page', this.currentPage);
      }, 
      startFromPage() {
        this.currentPage = this.startFromPage;
      },
      // usuń watch customLength jeżeli rerendering z :key zadziała
      customLength() {
        this.length = this.customLength;
        if (this.currentPage > this.length - 1) {
          this.currentPage = this.length - 1;
        }
      } 
    },
    methods: {
      animateCarousel() {
        this.$refs.wrapper.classList.add('scrolling');
        this.animateTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
          this.$refs.wrapper.classList.remove('scrolling');
        }, 500);
      },
      scrollWithNavdots(index) {
        this.currentPage = index - 1;
        this.currentTranslate = parseFloat(this.$refs.wrapper.style.transform.slice(11, -3));
      },
      onTouchStart() {
        clearInterval(this.autoplayInterval);
        if (event.type == 'touchstart') {
          this.moveStart = event.touches[0].screenX
        } else {
          this.moveStart = event.screenX;
          this.mousedown = true;
        }
      },
      onTouchMove() {
        let translate;

        if (event.type == 'touchmove') {
          this.move = event.touches[0].screenX - this.moveStart;
        } else if (event.type == 'mousemove' && this.mousedown == true) {
          this.move = event.screenX - this.moveStart
        }

        if (this.move < 0 && this.maxScrollRight || this.move > 0 && this.maxScrollLeft) {
          translate = this.translate + this.move*0.2;
        } else {
          translate = this.translate + this.move*0.5;
        }
        this.$refs.wrapper.style.transform = `translateX(${translate}px)`;
      }, 
      onTouchEnd() {
        this.test.touchstart = false;
        this.test.touchmove = false;
        if (Math.abs(this.move) > this.sensitivity) {
          if (this.move > 0 && !this.maxScrollLeft) {
            this.currentPage--
          } else if (this.move < 0 && !this.maxScrollRight) {
            this.currentPage++
          } else {
            this.animateCarousel();
          }
        } else if (Math.abs(this.move) < this.sensitivity && Math.abs(this.move) > 1) {
          this.animateCarousel();
        }

        this.$refs.wrapper.style.transform = `translateX(${this.translate}px)`;
        this.mousedown = false;
        this.moveStart = null;
        this.move = null;
      },
      setColumns() {
        this.viewportColumnsMatched = false;
        this.sortedColumns.forEach(cur => {
          if (window.matchMedia(`(min-width: ${cur[0]}px)`).matches) {
            this.viewportColumnsMatched = true;
            this.numberOfColumns = cur[1];
            this.$refs.wrapper.childNodes.forEach(cur => {
              cur.style.width = `${100/this.numberOfColumns}%`;
            });
          }
        });

        if (!this.viewportColumnsMatched) { 
          this.numberOfColumns = 1;
          this.$refs.wrapper.childNodes.forEach(cur => {
            cur.style.width = '100%';
          });
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.elementWidth = this.$slots.default[0].elm.offsetWidth;
        });
      },
      setActive() {
        this.sortedActive.forEach(cur => {
          if (window.matchMedia(`(min-width: ${cur[0]}px)`).matches) {
            this.isActive = cur[1];
          }
        });
      }, 
      runCarousel() {
        if (this.autoplay) {
          this.autoplayInterval = setInterval(() => {
            this.currentPage++ 
            if (this.currentPage == this.numberOfPages) this.currentPage = 0;
          }, this.autoplaySpeed * 1000);
        }
      }, 
    },
    mounted() {
      this.setColumns();
      this.setActive();
      this.runCarousel();
      window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        this.setColumns();
        this.setActive();
      });
    },
    destroyed() {
      clearInterval(this.autoplayInterval);
      clearTimeout(this.animateTimeout);
    }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript", done: false },
      { text: "Learn Vue", done: false },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", done: true },
      { text: "Build something awesome", done: true }
    ]
  },
})
```

Thank you in advance for your help, good people.